# Can I in-place construct in Rust?

Tags: c++, performance, rust, in-place, emplace

I like `emplace()`ing in C++ which allows to save on move construction and destruction: e.g. `strings.push_back("abcd"s)` means

> construct, move, destruct the temporary

while
`strings.emplace_back("abcd")` is just "construct".

Can anything similar be achieved in Rust (maybe with compiler optimizations)? The usual `vec.push(String::from("abcd"))` seems like (in C)

> construct + memcpy()

I'm also interested in cases which are more complex than just pushing strings into a vector.

Comment: [The placement by return / guaranteed copy elision RFC discusssion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2884) includes discussion of emplacement methods, named `*_with`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `emplace` feature mostly backed by [placement-new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) feature in C++ and similar unstable feature [was removed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27779#issuecomment-378416911) couple years ago from Rust. Therefore no, it is not possible do the similar with high-level code.

Nevertheless you are still able to use [`ptr::write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.write.html) and achieve the same behavior in unsafe code.